# Remove First from linked List

Tags: c#

I am trying to Remove my first value in my linked List  y but i am not sure if my code is right my remove last is working fine but my removeFirst is not.

```
 public class IntegerLinkedList
    {
        private class Node
        {
            public int value;
            public Node next;


            public Node(int v)
            {
                value = v;
                next = null;

            }

            internal int removeLast()
            {
                int value;
                if (next.next == null)
                {

                    value = next.value;
                    next = null;
                    return value;
                }
                else

                    return next.removeLast();

            }

            internal int removeFirst()
            {
                int value;
                if (next.next != null)
                {
                    value = next.value;
                    next = null;
                    return value;

                }

                else
                    return next.removeFirst();


            }
        }


        int count;
        Node start;
```

here is my code for removeFirst

```
public int removeFirst()
{

    int value;


 if  (start.next != null)
    {
        value = start.value;

    }
    else

        value = start.removeFirst();
    return value;
}
```

}

here is my link list

```
IntegerLinkedList myList = new IntegerLinkedList();
                myList.addFirst(1);
                myList.addFirst(2);
                myList.addFirst(3);
                myList.addFirst(4);


                Console.WriteLine(" expect to 4  to be removed" + myList.removeFirst());

}
```

it displays

removed 4 but i am not sure if thats correct

Comment: Where is `public int removeFirst()` in your code? Is it inside your `IntegerLinkedList` class? If so, why the `public` and `internal` methods?

Comment: Try stepping through your code. put a breakpoint on the first line of `removeFirst()`, and walk through it. See what it does, and where it does something other than what you expect it to.

Comment: Cos my internal methods need to be be my class called Node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
internal int removeFirst()
{
   int value;
   if (next.next != null)
   {
      value = next.value;
      next = null;
      return value;
   }
   else
      return next.removeFirst();
}
```

Is going to recursively traverse the list and cutoff the last element. It is effectively the same as `removeLast`.

Instead, you need to just do something like this:

```
Node currentStart = start;
start = start.next;
return currentStart.value;
```

The "start" `Node` object should no longer have any references pointing at it, so it will be GCd.

A quick note; you should likely remove "RemoveFirst" and "RemoveLast" from your Node class. Those are functions of the list; not nodes.

If you put all the methods in the list class (as you should!), addFirst (should be AddFirst) would be:

```
public void AddFirst(int item)
{
   Node newNode = new Node();
   newNode.value = item;

   newNode.next = start;
   start = newNode;
}
```

Your addLast requires iteration (or for you to track the "tail" node, your choice):

```
public void AddLast(int item)
{
   Node newNode = new Node();
   newNode.value = item;

   Node tailNode = start;
   while (tailNode.next != null)
      tailNode = tailNode.next;

   //In C++ you could cheat and do: while (tailNode = tailNode.next != null);

   //Tail node is now at the end
   tailNode.next = newNode;
}
```

Comment: So where would I put node Current start part in my code ? do i need to remove my Internal method

Comment: @RandomUsers the `start` node belongs in the list class. Random note, that node is more commonly called "head".

Comment: @RandomUsers Are you on the right track? Sort of. You appear to be combining the List and Node classes together in the Node class. A node in a linked list is *really* just a data structure, it shouldn't have any logic/methods. The List is where all the magic happens. Unless you are doing assembly/component design (unlikely given what you are working on) `internal` is the same as `public`. Also, the nested class thing is *really* not something you should do as a beginner (even though done correctly, you could get away with it here).

Comment: do you go about doing an addFirst then like my AddLast?? its because i'm following a class diagram

Comment: @BradlyDotNEt i meant how do i do addLast my add First works fine

Comment: And added (a way to do) that one in.

Comment: @BradlyDotNET When i do myList.addLast(); then console.writeline("remove" + removeFirst());  and then console.Writeline(removeLast()) should it then display 3 and 2 been removed?

Comment: @RandomUsers I don't know; you'd have to post the code sample (I can't see the state of your list). That certainly *sounds* reasonable.